# AcquireTokenAsync works normally without valid cilent secret

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, access-token

I can get the AccessToken to use with MS Graph using the code below

```
var credentials = new ClientCredential(accessRequest.ClientId, accessRequest.ClientSecret);
var authContext = new AuthenticationContext($"{accessRequest.Authoriy}/{accessRequest.Domain}/");
var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(accessRequest.Resource, credentials);
var graphAccess = new Library.Service.Implements.GraphCalendarService(result.AccessToken);
var mailsBox = await graphAccess.GetMailboxSettings(accessRequest.User);
```

The weird thing here is the value of [accessRequest.ClientSecret] used in first line = "qwerty".

Is this a bug or I need find another way to work with MS Graph(condition: need valid ClientId & ClientSecret)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes need to valid `clientId` and `Secret` and `resource or scope` for getting token once you get token then can request for `graph API endpoint`.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron I can still get the working token with the code in my first post and without valid `client secret` (in my case is [qwerty]). Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: Without `Client Secret` its not possible to get auth token, even if you get token that token would not able to fetch data. You are trying client_credential flow right?

Comment: I found the reason. It's the `TokenCache`, after clearing it, everything works as expected.

Comment: Yes, thats what I am trying to explain other then its not possible to get token without `application secret`.